# Can a unit object in a strict monoidal category have any nontrivial endomorphisms?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, monoidal-categories

I'm learning about strict monoidal categories and saw something interesting regarding the structure of units, which I hadn't seen before, and wanted to see if this was right.

Suppose we have a strict monoidal category with some unit $1$. Then can the unit object have any nontrivial endomorphisms, or is it that the identity is the only arrow to itself?

For a regular monoidal category this isn't true - for instance, $\Bbb Z$ is the unit in $\textbf{Ab}$ with the direct sum, and $\Bbb Z$ has plenty of arrows into itself. But is this necessarily true for a strict monoidal category?

The examples I've seen so far of strict monoidal categories seem to have the unit having only one arrow to itself, but I am not sure if this is always true.

Comment: Wikipedia gives the example of the category of endofunctors of a category $\mathbf{C}$, with the product being composition and the unit being the identity functor.  And in general, there can be plenty of endomorphisms of the identity functor.  (For example, if $\mathbf{C} = R{-}\mathbf{Mod}$, then for each $\alpha\in R$, multiplication by $\alpha$ gives such an endomorphism.)

Comment: @DanielSchepler Maybe do not post answers in the comments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Mac Lane strictness theorem asserts that every monoidal category is monoidally equivalent to a strict monoidal category. (See, for example, Theorem 2.8.5 in *Tensor Categories* by Etingof, Gelaki, Nikshych and Ostrik.)

The strictness assumption in your question therefore doesn’t matter:
if the statement were true for strict monoidal categories, then it would already be true for all monoidal categories.
But you’ve already provided a counterexample for this general case.

Answer (score 3):

The monoid of endomorphisms of the unit object of any monoidal category is commutative by the Eckmann-Hilton argument. Conversely, any commutative monoid is the monoid of endomorphisms of a unique strict monoidal category with one object, obtained by setting the tensor product and composition of endomorphisms to both be the commutative operation of the commutative monoid.